# How to rename column in AWS DMS task mapping

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, terraform, database-migration, aws-dms

The following mapping rules work fine up until rule 4 (the table column is created, the value inserted, and the original column deleted) where it fails to rename the column. Both the source and target are MySQL. The rule itself validates, a few variations I've tried error out on apply with Terraform, so I know the rule is technically valid, I just haven't figured out why it silently fails.

```
{
"rules": [
    {
        "rule-type": "selection",
        "rule-id": "1",
        "rule-name": "1",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "mydb",
            "table-name": "%"
        },
        "rule-action": "include"
    },
    {
        "rule-type": "transformation",
        "rule-id": "2",
        "rule-name": "2",
        "rule-target": "column",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "mydb",
            "table-name": "contacts"
        },
        "rule-action": "add-column",
        "value": "name_transformed",
        "expression": "hash_sha256($name)",
        "data-type": {
            "type": "string",
            "length": 255
        }
    },
    {
        "rule-type": "transformation",
        "rule-id": "3",
        "rule-name": "3",
        "rule-action": "remove-column",
        "rule-target": "column",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "mydb",
            "table-name": "contacts",
            "column-name": "name"
        }
    },
    {
        "rule-type": "transformation",
        "rule-id": "4",
        "rule-name": "4",
        "rule-action": "rename",
        "rule-target": "column",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "mydb",
            "table-name": "contacts",
            "column-name": "name_transformed"
        },
        "value": "name"
    }
]
}
```

One strange thing is that the documentation on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html) says:

> When used with the rule-action set to rename-column, expression specifies a new column name value.

But "rename-column" is actually not a valid rule-action, "rename" is as I have above.

I have tried #4 with both value and expression separately, both fail silently. With the two of them together Terraform validation fails.

Suggestions welcome!

Comment: Do you ever find the solution for this?

Comment: According to the AWS team responsible for DMS it was not supported.

Comment: In our case, we need to destroy DMS instance to make the rename rule works. Restart won't work, no idea why. But it is supported.

Comment: Then you should contact the DMS team at AWS to inform them, but at the time I posted this thread they told me it was not supported.

Comment: We're ok with destroying for now, so it's all set. Thanks for your info anw.

Comment: Strange, i've just created a new DMS instance and experiencing the exact same issue.